# Product sort order on category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, navigation

This is a bit of strange thing I've noticed.

My Category Sort Order is set to "position". For all categories.

Though, what happens is this:

If multiple products have the same "position" setting, instead of just sorting by product ID as it should, this is what happens:

- First product will be the one with the lowest ID, eg: 348.
- The rest all are sorted in a descending order starting with the product with the highest ID.

So After 348, the next product I have has an ID of 360, and then 359, 358, 357, and so on.

How does Magento actually decide which order to place the items in?

**Why I need this:**

I have "Next" / "Prev" Buttons on my product view page to allow a user to scroll through to the next product without going back to the category list.

And I'm sorting the products for the next/prev buttons using:

```
$order = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/default_sort_by');
$direction = 'asc';
$category_products = $cat->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort($order);
```

Which doesn't match that order as this code goes 348, 349, 350 etc.

Now I know I can just go and edit all the "position" values but I'm still curious as to why this happens.

**Specific Questions:**

1. How is Category Sort Order decided?
2. Where is this code?